# Will my new version app be rejected if i do not support Push Notifications in iOS8 or later

Tags: ios8, apple-push-notifications, review

I learned recently that  the registration method of Push Notifications have changed in iOS 8 , But  I didn't realize that before I submit my new version app , I want to know that if it  violate  the standard of app review and if it will be rejected.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about App Store compliance, not a coding issue. Please see [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/175701)

Comment: It will not be rejected. The old method is just deprecated.